# Prestashop Multiple customer id with same email-id

Tags: prestashop, user-registration

I'm using PrestaShop 1.5.5.0. 
My website is www.allworldfurniture.com and live now. I saw that one customer has registered 3 times with same name, same age and same mail id. How is it possible ? is  there any hacker trying to do so ?
Name, age and other stuff can be identical but how one mailid is registered multiple time ? any idea friends ? Shall I change something ?

Comment: from my findings this happen if you have the guest accounts enabled (purchase without registration feature)

Answer (score 0):

This is not likely a hacker. This is probably just someone who put their information into your form and accidentally submitted it three times. They probably thought their information hadn't submitted (possibly because of a slow network) and click submit again.

You should only allow users to send form data once every minute, for example, so that that doesn't happen again.

Comment: It the data has already written into the database then how can it write again ? I think it'd check for the already existed.

Comment: @Jnana If the browser sends a form but doesn't acknowledge that the data is sending (especially on a slow network connection) then he user might think it hasn't sent yet and click the submit button again, resenting the data more times.

Comment: I got the idea but is it possible that one data can write again without checking the validation point ? I can't understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

Hello everyone

to stop multiple customer id / Guest id with same email  PRESTASHOP 1.6

Go in this file \publicHTML\classes\Customer.php

remplace variable $ignore_guest true to false in function parameters like this

Lines 392-393

// public static function customerExists($email, $return_id = false, $ignore_guest = true)
   public static function customerExists($email, $return_id = false, $ignore_guest = false)

Enjoy